# Access to Wordpress dashboard when functions.php die

Tags: php, wordpress

I was editing the `functions.php` file of my activated theme in the Wordpress editor and I accidentally put a `die` in it. Now, whatever page I open in my website, even the Wordpress dashboard itself, it would run that code and die. I don NOT have access to cPanel nor phpMyAdmin. I wonder if I can do anything to gain access to the dashboard again?

Comment: `functions.php` is fundamental to running your WP site, so if it has an error (or in this case an ill-placed `die`), then your site simply won't run - front end or back end. You will need to edit the functions.php on the server to remove `die`. If you don't have access to cPanel, how were you editing the files in the first place?

Comment: @FluffyKitten through the built-in editor of Wordpress (under Appearance menu)

Comment: Eek... its not recommended to change files that way - there's no version control and no way of recovery. You will need to speak to whoever manages the hosting to get access because there's no other way of changing the code I'm afraid.

Comment: You need to access Cpanel or FTP for editing the file.

Comment: @Gaurav I do not have access to cPanel or FTP. I still have the cookies and sessions for admin user for Wordpress dashboard but I cannot do anything with that. I wonder there is any route or API of Wordpress that does not run functions.php and let me do something at least!

Comment: @M.Mohammadi without Cpanel or FTP you can't access file.